# How can I get the text from this jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
$(this).parents('li').each(function(n, li) {
  var a = $(li).children('a').clone();
  bc.prepend(a).text();
});
```

How can I retrieve and clone only text value from `<a>`? This method only gets me the whole DOM. Can I change `<a>` to `<i>`?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(this).closest('li').each(function(n, li) {
    $(li).children('a').replaceWith(function(){
        return $('<i/>').append($(this).contents())
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Bh2FQ/)